# Sparse Inverse Fourier Transforms

Tags: fft, dft, ifft

I'm looking to compute an IDFT but my input is very sparse:

Example:

- IDFT length: 7,408,800 (complex floats)
- Sparsity: 96.61% to 99.99%

---

I found this [Sparse FFT](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/netmit/sFFT/) website but it looks like the library deals with sparse inputs to *standard* DFT - not IDFT - also it doesn't look like it is not for consumer use.

Are there any techniques I can employ to improve performance for sparse IDFT - before even changing my DFT library? And now, are there any *available* libraries that give performance improvements for spare IDFT?

Comment: You can easily modify the input and output of a DFT (it's just time reversals and complex conjugates, no "actual" computation) to make an IDFT. However, would be cool if you could explain how long your DFT is and how sparse it is, i.e. how many of the inputs are non-zero. That would allow for an algorithmic recommendation!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ranges somewhere from 50% to 95% sparsity

Comment: uh, does that mean 70% to  98% are actual non-zero values? Because: that's not very sparse, and the regular FFT will be the best you can do.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just calculated, 0.00329% of the data is non-zero (99.99% sparse) at the worst case. In the best case 3.38% is non-zero (96.61% sparsity).

Comment: As you can see, this is seriously sparse

Comment: that **is** seriously sparse, indeed. What the lengths of your IDFTs?

Comment: @MarcusMüller around 30MB. The test I just ran was of size 7,408,800

Comment: for a single transform!? wow! That's how many values?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I meant 7408800 values - the data size is around 30MB

Comment: Cool! I'll go ahead and add that info to your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry I accidentally edited over your edit, ill rollback

Comment: don't worry, just combine!

Comment: Sparse FFT is for sparse output of the transform. You have sparse input so it is not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

The FFT is faster than the naive DFT through matrix-vector products because it can reuse many intermediate results.

However, for inputs this sparse, there's really not much that can be re-used, even in the best case.

So, the most efficient way here is probably to work straight forward:

- Allocate the space ($N=7408800$ values) for your output (initialize with zeros) $o$.
- Go through your input $i$. Nested loops:

  - For every nonzero input index $n$:

    - For every output index $k$: add $i_ne^{j2\pi \frac{nk}N}$ to $o_k$.

Notes:

- since with sparse input, your output is non-sparse, it's usually faster to traverse the input only once, but the output many times, instead of the other way around (that is because memory is much faster when addressed linearly)
- to calculate the complex exponential, you can use SIMD-accelerated calculations, because the values are in consecutive addresses and have proportional phase. LibVOLK has a number of implementations that might be helpful for fast calculation here.

Comment: I'm doing a complex to complex IDFT - so I need the full output. I think the half output applies to real to complex DFT's

Comment: What I'm getting from your answer is to essentially implement the classical DFT, because the FFT is not so optimal for sparse data. Is this correct?

Comment: well, not really, no: the classical DFT would be multiplying a lot of zeros. What you're doing here is omitting everything that's just a zero multiplication. The result is the same.

Comment: Do you think this'll be similar to what SFFT does? I'm trying to get the library working, but maybe I don't need it

Comment: No, it's not. It's the IDFT.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and implement this now

Comment: An IDFT is a DFT with a negative exponent right? Maybe SFFT's DFT sparsity is fine, as I can just flip the exponent (i.e. `FFTW_BACKWARD`)

Comment: an SFFT is not a DFT; DFT is one processing step in SFFT. However, FFTW has nothing to do with SFFT; you're confusing something here.

Comment: and as said, an FFT (which is what FFTW offers) will not be efficient (see my answer!)

Comment: I used `FFTW_BACKWARD` as an example of a negative exponent. In fftw, the IDFT works nearly identically to the DFT - you just change `FFTW_FORWARD` to `FFTW_BACKWARD`, which are just variables for 1 and -1, the exponents. What I was  saying is maybe SFFT works similarly, so it doesn't only offer sparsity gains for DFT's but for IDFTs too (which is just a DFT with a negative exponent)

Comment: I ask this because I'm sure their implementation will be much faster / more robust than something I implement

Comment: ... and my answer exactly addresses that.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I doubt a simple switch between flags help. However, why don't you just try it and tell us the result?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi I think you're still confusing FFTW, FFT, SFFT and DFT as terms. FFTW is not "special" in how it does the IFFT: it's just an IDFT; you know the DFT and IDFT formulas, and that exponent sign change is exactly the difference.

Comment: Do you know the time complexity of your solution

Comment: I believe SFFT is klog(n). Here you iterate through n, implying its at best O(n)

Comment: again, you're confusing "SFFT" with something else. Can't help you if you're not using the same vocabulary as the rest of us. I literally don't know what you're referring to, and also, my answer is sufficient to infer the number of operations necessary.

Comment: SFFT means sparse fft, its the library I've been speaking about (in my question)

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi in the notations of Marcus and MIT, $k$ and $n$ are swapped, and the complexity of the algorithm is not linear. Please just read the source code of SFFT, or at least its papers to understand how SFFT works, and thenceforth many of your questions would not need to be asked.

Comment: @AlexTP so instead of answering my question about time complexity you tell me to go and read a scientific paper?

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi yes, if you want to know how to use SFFT for your specific problem. Isn't it your purpose? If you just want to know the complexity, Marcus, as the author, has already given the answer. The complexity is calculated the same way SFFT authors claimed the complexity O(klog(n)).

Cited from the SFFT website 
*This code is provided for research purposes only. At this stage the code is not a standalone portable library and cannot be used blindly.*

Using the library without understanding the theory will be dangerous.

Comment: What is $j$? The notations confusing

Comment: The imaginary unit. It's pretty usual to denote that with $j$ instead of $i$ in things that deal with signals, because a lot of these disciplines arose from electrical engineering, and $i$ was already used for currents. Anyway, don't you think you should have been asking about understanding of the answer before proposing other things in the comments? And this is really basic...

Comment: I implemented this answer and it's orders of magnitudes slower than a standard DFT

Comment: well, then you've implemented it in a bad way – the numbers are pretty clear: at your level of sparsity, not doing a normal DFT or even a FFT is faster if one is writing normally performant code.

Comment: it completed 0.04% of the DFT in 3 hours - I had to cancel it

Comment: yeah, that sounds like a really strange implementation.

Comment: This approach improved performance for *incredibly* sparse data (99.999973%) - essentially 1 non-zero in millions. FFTW is still ***orders of magnitudes*** faster for the sparsity in question: 96.61% to 99.99%